# Remove space except tab in a text line

Tags: java

I am reading a tab-delimited text file line by line which is extremely messy and trying to get the unique columns names out of it.

The problem is it contains tabs as field separator but some column names have space in their names! I am using

```
String[] cols = line.split("\\t");
```

which seems that is not working properly since for some cases it gets the spaces as separators! Is using regex a good solution? If yes, could you advise what regex removes white spaces from a string but keeps the tabs?

Data is like:

```
Sever ID    Name
12221       zxsz
```

Comment: You must post a sample of the data. Without that we really cannot help.

Comment: Your approach is ok. You can try `line.replaceAll("\\t", "|")` and print line to see if the column names are separated using tab instead spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Tab in a string literal is just "\t". "\\t" is a literal backslash followed by a "t". Having said that, either method works for me:

```
public class Scratch2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String welk = "anna one\tanna two\tanna three";
        System.out.println("\\t");
        String[] annas = welk.split("\t");
        for (String anna : annas) {
            System.out.println(anna);
        }
        System.out.println("\\\\t");
        annas = welk.split("\\t");
        for (String anna : annas) {
            System.out.println(anna);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
\t
anna one
anna two
anna three
\\t
anna one
anna two
anna three
```

The simplest explanation is that your input strings don't contain the whitespace characters you think they do.